# Translating customer address templates

Tags: magento2.3

I have modified customer address templates to include some custom address attributes I have added and this works great. However as part of the modification I need to include some static text that needs to be translated to the right language (presumably website language).

I know I can use `{{trans "text here"}}` directive in transactional email templates to translate parts of the template text. However in address templates this does not work - it simply outputs the directive verbatim (i.e. the entire directive not just the text inside the directive)

What is the proper way to translate an address template?

Comment: You can see the `Address Templates` can me modified in store view scope. Create language specific configuration for each store view.

Comment: Yes, that was my fallback scenario, but that means I have to repeat the changes in every store view having no way to guarantee consistency. Doable but not practical.

Comment: But I think..This is a way...May be someone know another solution.